# I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS and can't connect to wifi (no wifi adapter found) and bluetooth devices

Tags: 18.04, wireless, bluetooth

```
$ lshw -C network
```

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c2100000-c21fffff memory:c2200000-c2203fff memory:c2204000-c2204fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 15
       serial: 7c:10:c9:ac:75:6e
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.045.08-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.218 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:128 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c5204000-c5204fff memory:c5200000-c5203fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

```
lsusb
```

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 322e:202c  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:3563 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
lspci
```

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b64 (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9bc4 (rev 05)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 06f9
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 06ed
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 06ef
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 06e8
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 06e0
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 06d3
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b0 (rev f0)
00:1d.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b5 (rev f0)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b6 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 068d
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 06c8
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 06a3
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 06a4
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f99 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron Technology Inc Device 5404 (rev 03)
03:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7961
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

```
rfkill list all
```

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Why 18.04? A newer release probably supports that WiFi out-of-the-box.

Comment: The `322e:202c` is your webcam, and `13d3:3563` is the MediaTek Bluetooth device. Your wireless card is the 7961 as seen in `lspci`, but that doesn't have any support with kernels lower than 5.14. If you are using an ASUS TUF notebook, then your only viable solution is to install Ubuntu 21.10 or one of the daily builds of the upcoming 22.04 to have full network connectivity.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I wish to use ROS melodic and to my knowledge it works with 18.04 the best.

Comment: @matigo I had previous installed Ubuntu 20 and the adapter were working but i had to downgrade it due melodic running best in 18.04

Comment: If you have specific reasons to use specific versions of Ubuntu on newer hardware, then you may need to compromise by using a different WiFi adapter or using 18.04 within a virtual machine 

Comment: @Viral Doshi There is no Ubuntu 20

Comment: @David I'm sorry, it was 21.10

Comment: @mchid made the changes, thank you.

Comment: @matigo I will look into it, I'm not so keen on doing that atm!

Comment: @ViralDoshi Thanks. Also take a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/425180/167115). There is a script you can run and then you can post the output of the script to the Ubuntu pastebin. The script scrubs identifying information and gives a complete diagnostic output for people to inspect. Then, you can post a link to the pastebin in your question. This will help.

Comment: @ViralDoshi However, if you have already figured out the problem is with drivers, that may not be necessary.